# Deleting Data From SQL database causes parts of app to stop loading?

Tags: android

I am developing a text messaging app and have run into a weird issue that I have tried for a long time to fix and can not so I am wondering if there is something going on that is above me.

To explain the scenario, I have my application class below:

```
class Texpert : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        setupDebugNotification(applicationContext)
        database = MessagesDatabase(applicationContext)
    }

    companion object {

        lateinit var database: MessagesDatabase
        var cache: LruCache<String, Bitmap>? = null
        val memoryCache: LruCache<String, Bitmap>
            get() {
                if (cache != null)
                    return cache!!

                return synchronized(this) {
                    val cacheSize = (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024).toInt() / 8
                    cache = object : LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
                        override fun sizeOf(key: String, bitmap: Bitmap): Int = bitmap.byteCount / 1024
                    }
                    cache!!
                }
            }

      }
}
```

This works great, except when the user is in the inbox and deletes a conversation (where I delete that conversation from the system messages database and from my apps database "MessagesDatabase") the contact pictures of the users inside my recyclerview stop updating (they are populated through an async task using the memoryCache if the image is available which they are) and do not update freezing to the ones that were visible before the delete happened.

For example to be clear:

Before delete:

Person A - Picture A
Person B - Picture B
Person C - Picture C
        ...
Person M - Picture M

Then during the delete:

Person A - Picture A
Person B - Picture B
but if I scroll down
Person M - Picture A
Person N - Picture B

Here is the function to get the conversation photo to be displayed:

```
fun getConversationPhoto(context: Context, cache: LruCache<String, Bitmap>?, contactPreferences: SharedPreferences, address: String): Bitmap? {
        if (address.contains(","))
            return getGroupPhoto(context, cache, contactPreferences, address)

        if (cache != null) {
            val cached = cache.get(address)

            if (cached != null)
                return cached
        }

        var photo = openSmallPhoto(context, address)

        if (photo == null)
            photo = getLetter(context, contactPreferences, address)

        cache?.put(PhoneUtility.formatPhoneNumber(address), photo)

        return photo
    }
```

Here is the Adapter Bind Function (for the item view type, 1 is single and 2 is group convo):

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ConversationViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (inbox.isClosed)
            return

        inbox.moveToPosition(position)
        val thread = inbox.getString(threadId)

        normal?.applyTo(holder.layout)
        val contactColor: Int
        holder.time.text = DateUtility.getTimeOfDay(inbox.getLong(date))

        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            2 -> {
                val prev = holder.card.tag as AsyncTask<*, *, *>?

                if (prev != null && prev.status != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
                    prev.cancel(true)

                holder.card.tag = BitmapLoaderTask(context, memoryCache, contactPreferences, holder.profile).execute(inbox.getString(groupAddress))
                holder.name.text = contactPreferences.getString(ContactUtility.getGroupIdentifier(inbox.getString(groupAddress)), inbox.getString(groupName))
                contactColor = ColorUtility.getAppColor(context)
            }
            else -> {
                BitmapLoaderTask(context, memoryCache, contactPreferences, holder.profile).execute(inbox.getString(address))
                holder.name.text = ContactUtility.getName(context, inbox.getString(address))
                contactColor = ColorUtility.getNameColor(context.resources, contactPreferences, inbox.getString(address), inbox.getString(name))
            }
        }
    }
```

The bitmap async task simply calls the getConversationPhoto method shown above

In an attempt to stop this I changed from a static memory cache to using a singleton but that did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: Just so I understand clearly, you are deleting a conversation thread and when re-loading your list, the contact pictures aren't displaying?

Comment: @WadeWilson Not quite. I am deleting a conversation thread in the inbox, and while the delete process is still happening (it takes multiple seconds) scrolling through the conversation list the contact pictures (which are gotten from the memoryCache) do not change. Essentially the recyclerview stops loading the pictures and whatever pictures were in the view holder once the delete started are the ones that stay there while scrolling.

Comment: Are the images stored in the same database? Try deleting a conversation and then scroll through you conversation list and place a breakpoint inside of you onBindViewHolder and make sure that you are loading the correct images. Seems like an issue with the same key being used to load the images from the cache.

Comment: @WadeWilson The images are originally loaded using the contacts system database (MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap) and then added to the LRUCache, which is where they come from when scrolling.

Comment: Are you loading the images on the fly as needed or are you pre-loading them into the LRUCache before you display them inside of the RecyclerView?

Comment: @WadeWilson I have added the code for my get photo utility method. The first time it is loaded using android system api and added to the cache and after that it is retrieved from the cache using the users address as a key

Comment: Thanks for adding more code, can I see your ViewHolder binding code more specifically?

Comment: @WadeWilson Added the binding code (minus a few lines that are irrelevant to image loading). I will say that the async task check is there so it will cancel loading past images in the event that I need to load another one (if you scroll really quickly through the inbox it does not show every different contact that it loaded).

Comment: I don't see where you are getting address from. It appears to be reused over and over again. Also, for the else statement inside of the when expression, you constantly load new BitmapLoaderTask and never cancel older ones especially if they can't be recycled for the new item at position. Also, I don't see any code here that checks your cache to see if a bitmap exist before loading a task to fetch an image. Maybe those could be the source of your problem. The only way to tell for sure is to delete a conversation and start scrolling and place  breakpoint.

Comment: @WadeWilson The key for the cache comes from the line inside the BitmapTask creation inbox.getString(address) also the check of the cache for an already existing image happens inside the getConversationPhoto method where it says if cached != null then cache = cached.get(address).

Comment: @WadeWilson I have just realized that I use an async task when deleting the messages as well, so perhaps the issue is that the background thread is being used up which means the BitmapTask can not run until that other delete task is finished

Comment: Yes, that is correct. After API level HONEYCOMB, the api will execute task serially instead of in parallel. You can force the api to execute in parallel by calling .executeOnExecutor (AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR., Object[]). Hope that helps.

Comment: @WadeWilson Wow that works wonders!! Are there any negative effects or caveats for forcing this behavior?

Comment: It'll steals processor time running all threads concurrently but once all of you images are loaded into you cache, you no longer need to run the task and it's magnitudes cheaper. A possible solution would be to continue to load the bitmap task serially and delete your threads on a custom worker background thread so you don't have too worry about several threads running concurrently.